# Update SQL command C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-update

I'm trying to update a database from my program in C#.

Here is my code which connects to the database and the attempts to update the `date` column in my `RoomsTable` table. It looks good to me but nothing happens in the database.

```
updateConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
updateConnection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\users\spreston\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\roomChecksProgram\roomChecksProgram\roomsBase.accdb";
updateConnection.Open();

MessageBox.Show("Connected");

string updateCommand = "UPDATE RoomsTable SET Date Checked='9/27/2012'";
updateAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(updateCommand, updateConnection);

updateConnection.Close();
updateConnection.Dispose();
```

I don't know why it isn't working. It looks to me like everything is there.

Comment: You need to run an `execute()` method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `OleDBCommand`

```
string updateCommand = "UPDATE RoomsTable SET [Date Checked]='9/27/2012'";
updateCommand = new OleDbCommand(updateCommand, updateConnection);

updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
updateConnection.Close();
```

maybe you could refractor the code using `Using statement` and *parameterized the query*. and column name `Date Checked` should be *escaped* with brackets.

```
string updateCommand = "UPDATE RoomsTable SET [Date Checked]=@checkedDate WHERE ID = @id"; // '9/27/2012'
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("connectionStringHERE"))
{
    using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandText = updateCommand;
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkedDate", this.dateTimePicker1.Value)
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", row.roomID);
        try
        {
            comm.Open();
            conn.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(OleDbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm yeah I was following a tutorial I found on the web..(i have no database experience) and it used the method I used. It was for an access databse and everything which is what im using.

Comment: I tried your method and im getting errors ("Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.OleDB.OleDBCommand' to string) and ('string' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteNonQuery'

Comment: and I do have using System.Data.OldeDb in my code at the top.

Comment: ok i got those errors solved, but now when i run it crashes and the error says there is an error in my update statement whenever .executenonquert is called

Comment: @Stonep123 where is this `9/27/2012` coming from?

Comment: I just put that in there to see if it put it in there. Once I get it updating I have a dateTime picker on my form that I want to grab the date from.

Comment: Eventually I want to insert it into a specific record, according to the ID number. But i just want to try and get it to update anything

Comment: oh i see it, you must escape the column name because it has a space. is should be `[Date Checked]`

Comment: and Ive got it inserting into the proper record now to with UPDATE RoomsTable SET [Date Checked]='9/27/2012' WHERE ID=" + row.roomID

Comment: although now im running into trouble when i want to insert the value of the dateTimePicker into the command. "UPDATE RoomsTable SET [Date Checked]=" + "'" + this.dateTimePicker1.Value + "'" +" " +  "WHERE ID=" + row.roomID;

Comment: you will have no difficulty when you parameterized the query. see my updated answer above :)

Comment: ok i wil do that, one more thing. I have my database attached to a datagrid view and when i run my update code and all that the datagrid view date changes, but when i open my database up, it hasnt modified the actual database

Comment: we can't move on chat since you don't have enough reputation. anyway, did you refresh your database? or did the connection points on the correct database?

Comment: it points to the correct database. I mean the sql query updates the database in the connection string, and that database in the connection string is the one connected to my datagrid view, and it displays correctly in the datagrid view so it must be. How do i refresh the database?

Comment: i'm not familiar with the interface of `MsAccess` but to simply refresh the table is to close it and open the table again.

Comment: yeah ive tried that. still nothing. Is it because im not resaving the modified table from within the program? Can I email you or something? this is getting pretty lengthy

Answer (score 0):

you have to write this:

```
updateConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
updateConnection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\users\spreston\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\roomChecksProgram\roomChecksProgram\roomsBase.accdb";

updateConnection.Open();

MessageBox.Show("Connected");

string updateCommand = "UPDATE RoomsTable SET Date Checked= '"+9/27/2012+"' ";

updateAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(updateCommand, updateConnection);

updateConnection.Close();
updateConnection.Dispose();
```

Comment: Always use parameters in your queries to avoid sql injection.  Your updateCommand string isn't what you think it is.